# UITableView's viewForHeaderInSection method: accessing a cell's visual properties

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am defining a header row for my `UITableView` using the `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method, and I wanted to get the X coodinate from the first row to position some labels, because I'm moving about the labels in the row constantly and would like to define those coordinates in the storyboard. But it's not working: the X coordinate is always 0. Here is the attempt:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    float x = tableView.frame.origin.x;
    float y = tableView.frame.origin.y;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y - 22, tableView.bounds.size.width, 12)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0];
    view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    LogCell *cell = (LogCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];

    UILabel *dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.label_DATE.frame.origin.x, 0, 65, 22)];
    dateLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    dateLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    dateLabel.text = @"DATE";

    UILabel *locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.label_LOC.frame.origin.x, 0, 65, 22)];
    locationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    locationLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
    locationLabel.text = @"LOC";

    [view addSubview:dateLabel];
    [view addSubview:locationLabel];

    return view;
}
```

Is there some way to properly get a row from the `UITableView` to ascertain the X/Y coordinates of the cell's labels?

Comment: Why do you expect `x` to be anything but 0? The table is at the left edge if its parent view. And the frame for `view` should have an origin of 0,0 anyway. And have you verified that `cell` is not `nil`?

Comment: The `x` for the labels is not 0, it's 20, 92, 127, etc. At least, it is when I'm prototyping the cell in the Storyboard editor.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do exactly? It sounds like you're moving labels inside a custom section header but its unclear which coordinate from your code you're checking.

Comment: @Aaron I'm pretty sure the goal is to have labels in the section header that line up with labels in the cells.

Comment: Ah, `cell` indeed is `nil`. I am just trying to manually get the first `UITableViewCell` from `tableView` in order to position labels in my header.

Comment: First of all you are using a variable "label_DATE", this type of naming convention is not used in IOS. Table view's origin always (0,0)   if you are creating it with table view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
LogCell *cell = (LogCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:0];
```

is the same as:

```
LogCell *cell = (LogCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nil];
```

You aren't passing in an index path:

Try this:

```
LogCell *cell = (LogCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];
```

Comment: Works! But there's a slight delay and it moves the labels after the table is drawn. Maybe I'll go back to hardcoding the `x` coordinate again.